# Add all the content type columns as indexes inside a Document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, power-automate

I have this flow which do those main 3 actions:-

1. Create a new Document library
2. Add a custom content type
3. Remove the built-in Document content type

[image]

[image]

[image]

now i want to get all the fields inside the content type (which are eligible to be added as index) and add them as Index to the new document library, is there a way to do so?

Thanks